# error in child class definition of templated class inheritance

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17

I am defining class `A` that can take function as template argument. Class `B` inherits class `A`. However, there are errors  `B: use of class template requires template argument list` and multiple other errors. I am thinking that declaration of class `B` has gone wrong. However, I am not using any template for class `B`. Can someone comment?

```
#include <iostream>

void f_global()
{
    std::cout << "top level function\n";
}

template<typename F>
class A
{
public:
    F f1;
    A(F fun1) : f1(fun1) {}
    void fa();
};

template<typename F>
void A<F> :: fa()
{
    std::cout << "From A<F>::fa()\n";
    f1();
}

template<typename F>
class B : public A<F> //error
{
public:
    void fb();
};

void B::fb() //error
{
    std::cout << "From B::fb()\n";
    A::f1(); //Can access f1()?
}
int main()
{
    A obja(f_global); //error?
    obja.fa();
    B objb;
    objb.fb();
}
```

Comment: Just like you did `template<typename F>
void A<F> :: fa()`, you need to do the same thing for `void B::fb()`.  You also have a lot of other syntax/typo errors.

Comment: Furthermore, since the template A does not have a default constructor, there is no way to construct template B, which expects its superclass to have a default constructor. There are a number of fundamental problem with template usage, here.

Comment: You say "I am not using any template for class `B`", but you are; `template<typename F> class B ...` says that `B` is a template.

Comment: Do you want B to be a template class? Maybe a specialization of A?

Comment: In your main, you call f2, but where is f2()?

Comment: Corrected `fa()` call from main

Comment: `B` is not a class. It's another template. And, it's already been pointed out to you why template `B` cannot inherit from template `A`. What else are you unclear about?

Comment: How can I inherit `A` to `B`? Can you put that in answer?

Comment: Why are you using a template? If you always use a global void function taking no parameter, then you can use that type. If not, then providing one or 2 alternatives might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is often useful to explain what you are trying to achieve. There are many very smart people here which would come up with solutions to your problem which have absolutely nothing to do with yours.

Now, I've tried to guess what you wanted to achieve. Since you call `fa` from `fb`, I assumed `B` is a `template`. If not, then at least `fb` should be a templated function. However, since you don't pass the function to execute as argument to `fb`, I finally guessed that your `class B` is intented to be a `template`.

So, your global function is fine:

```
void f_global()
{
    std::cout << "top level function\n\n";
}
```

Your `class A` is ok, but for clearness, I'd use `F` for the function type and `F*` for the function pointer (*), and I would also store the `function` as a `private` member. However, to respect the code in your question, I'll leave it as a `public` member.

**EDIT (*)**
As @Phil1970 pointed out, `F` is more general than `F*`as it would work with lambdas and `std::function`.

```
template <typename F>
class A
{
public:
    A(F fun) : _f {fun} {}
    void fa() { std::cout << "From A<F>::fa()\n"; _f(); }
    F _f;
};
```

As you correctly figured out, there is a problem with your `class B`. First of all, if `template <typename F> B` inherits from `template <typename F> A`, you should be able to construct an object of type `A<F>` from within the constructor of `B<F>`. In other words, `B<F>` should be able to construct `A<F>`, and therefore, you should pass the function `f_global` to the constructor of `class B<F>`.

```
template <typename F>
class B : public A<F>
{
public:
    B(F* fun) : A<F>(fun) {}
    void fb() { std::cout << "From B::fb()\n"; A<F>::_f(); }
    void fb1() { std::cout << "From B::fb1()\n"; this->template _f(); }
    using A<F>::_f;
    void fb2() { std::cout << "From B::fb2()\n"; _f(); }
};
```

I added functions `fb1` and `fb2` to show you how to call the callable `_f` member using template deduction and using the keyword `using`.

Comment: Is it possible to use auto template detection feature in C++17 instead of specifying pointers?

Comment: If you mean if the constructor can take a function of type F instead of F*, the answer is yes. F will then be deduced as void (*)(). In my case, F is deduced as void (). In both cases, the argument fun is a pointer to f_global.

Comment: @ewr3243 I edited the question to keep your original format from the question.

Comment: `F` instead of `F*` is more general as it would works with `std::function` and lambdas. Or I am missing something?

Comment: @MFnx As mentioned in question, is `void B::fb()` correct and can you comment on `main()`  creating object of class?

Comment: @ewr3243 I tried to answer that in the first part of the answer. B<F> must be able to construct A<F>. Your template A has not a default constructor, and therefore, B cannot construct A. So, you must write a constructor of tenplate class B and define their how A must be constructed. Therefore, I added a constructor in the template class B.